# How to skip setting an attribute using the Builder pattern

Tags: java, builder, lombok

Using Lombok to build Phone object. How to skip setting an attribute say "name" using the Builder pattern, if for some reason it would be null

```
protected Phone createPhone(String number, String name) {
    return Phone.builder()
        .number(number)
        .name(name)
        .type(PhoneType.MOBILE)
        .build();
}
```

Comment: You'd store your `Builder` in a variable, and only call `#name(name)` if the name wasn't null. Alternatively, throw an exception (e.g. `IllegalArgumentException` or in the spirit of lombok, `@NonNull`)) if the `name` provided is null, as that would be a "developer error" and something that should be caught/fixed

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to "override" builder methods in Lombok. For example you could do it this way (simplified `Phone`):

```
@Builder
@Getter @Setter
public class Phone {
    private String number;
    private String name;
    
    public static class PhoneBuilder {
        // Lombok does not generate name "setter" but uses this instead
        public PhoneBuilder name(String name) {
            if (null == name) {
                // throw or ignore or whatever
                throw new NullPointerException("Name NULL");
            }
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```